# Flex and word-break inconsistent behavior between FF and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a basic layout using flex:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">LongTextWithNoBreaks...</div>
  <div class="right">Short text</div>
</div>
```

The left div is defined with `flex-grow: 3` and the right with `flex-grow: 9`. Normally the right div is 3 times the size of the left. However when I have a very long text on the left with no white spaces, it works fine in chrome, but not so much in FF (35.0.1).

**Note:** I'm using `word-wrap: break-word;` so that the text will break.

Full code:

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  .left {
    background: gray;
    flex: 3 0 0;
  }
  .right {
    color: #333;
    background: green;
    flex: 9 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocious
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I meant to use `word-wrap` in the snippet and used `word-break` instead.

**Note:** Using `break-all` isn't a good solution since it breaks by character and not by word. `word-break` tries first to break by word and only breaks in a middle of a word if necessary.

Comment: Your runnable snippet is useless because the CSS is missing. If you are going to include one, you need to make it actually useful. Also, you should not have to force readers to click on an external fiddle link - after all, that is what Stack Snippets was designed to do.

Comment: Removed snippet. I prefer to start with a small code example and the full version.

Comment: OK, but the CSS is still missing.

Comment: It's in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Like I said, you shouldn't force readers to click an external link to see the essential code. JSFiddle is particularly notorious for random downtimes, so the link won't always be accessible throughout the day. And given that this is a CSS question, it makes sense to include the CSS. Is there a lot of CSS code in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70343/discussion-between-sions-and-boltclock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the missing piece in FF is to add `min-width: 0` to the left element.

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  .left {
    background: gray;
    flex: 3 0 0;
    min-width: 0;
  }
  .right {
    color: #333;
    background: green;
    flex: 9 0 0;
    min-width: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    supercalifragilisticexpialidocious supercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocioussupercalifragilisticexpialidocious
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Hello, World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly correct. This will eventually be required in Chrome, too, once they implement the new default value for "min-width": https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333533